# Get form data after submiting form for shorting items

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, form-submit, ajaxform

```
<form id="pricing_plan_form" action="" method="POST" class="prcCF_box">
    <div class="price_form_opt">
        <div class="pcf_col">
            <div class="pcf_col_inner">
                <h2 class="number_no">1.</h2>
                <span>
                    <span class="title_1">Are your married?</span>
                    <span class="title_not">(or might as well be)</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="pcf_col_op_fields pcf_swt">
                <span>no</span>
                <label class="switch">
                    <input class="onoffsw" name="married" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider_swt round"></span>
                </label>
                <span>yes</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pcf_col">
            <div class="pcf_col_inner">
                <h2 class="number_no">2.</h2>
                <span>
                    <span class="title_1"># of children running<br>wild in your house?</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="pcf_col_op_fields">
                <span id="ratext1">0</span>
                <input name="children" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" class="slider_ran" id="myRange">
                <span>5+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pcf_col">
            <div class="pcf_col_inner">
                <h2 class="number_no">3.</h2>
                <span>
                    <span class="title_1"># of siblings who<br>still talk to you?</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="pcf_col_op_fields">
                <span id="ratext2">0</span>
                <input name="siblings" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" class="slider_ran" id="myRange2">
                <span>10+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var frm = $('#pricing_plan_form');
        frm.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

I am new in javascript/jquery. I am creating a pricing sorting option with the form. when the user selects the necessary values the automatically a recommended packet will be shown. I have created the form when I submit the form data of the whole page is shown. I am not getting form data separately. Can anyone help me with the problem? I will be using it on PHP. And the form and product items are on the same page.

Comment: added to my answer the fact about the original HTML form submit button

Answer (score 1):

```
`               $('#pricing_plan_form').on('submit', function () {
                    var that = $(this),
                        url = that.attr('action'),
                        method = that.attr('method'),
                        data = {};
                    that.find('[name]').each(function ( index, value ) {
                        var that = $(this),
                            name = that.attr('name'),
                            value = that.val();
                        data[name] = parseInt(value);
                    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have feeling (not 100% sure) you have to disable them selectively, would something like this work?

```
if (your condition) {
   $("#formField").attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
   $("#formField").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Another thing is that you have a full submit button which will trigger the original form even if you will make yours in ajax, the underlining HTML doesn't know what magic JS is doing behind it's back (and if it should stop submitting the form). To fix that you can make form without a valid HTML submit button, and only rely on the bind JS to do the job. Would remove

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And just make a button of type button (no pun intended) which then could do extra JS hackery without HTML doing its thing:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

```
<button type="button|submit|reset">
```

Comment: I have tried to change the button type the problem is the same. i am getting data like raw dump 
https://i.postimg.cc/13hQQSfp/screenshot-414.png
https://i.postimg.cc/50khkdhQ/screenshot-415.png
https://i.postimg.cc/d3kzbNFH/screenshot-416.png

Not the data which I submitted on the form how can I get that data through ajax. it could solve my problem

Comment: Why you are attaching to the submit event on the form, which you are trying to avoid? Attach it to the onClick event to the button itself

Comment: And make sure to return false in the function as returning true will tell the form to be sent

Comment: I have figured it out by this. I was needed the data and by this way I got it. thanks

Comment: So then write exactly what you have done to fix it in an answer and I think you can accept your own answer as solution, this way somebody else having the same problem will get the solution too

Comment: I just get the data by input name field and then short it through. I have added the answer on top you can check it.

Comment: Looks good, if I can recommend for the future to use https://jsfiddle.net/ it's a great tool to share both HTML/JS/CSS in one and easier for people to interact and experiment with them. From my expierence, the questions who are using the jsfiddle (or similar) gain more answers/discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will remember it next time.